# Splitting a line, then searching for string

Tags: python, string, loops, split

sry im still new to python.

My complete code so far:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.split("\t")
    if my_var in line[1]:
        print line[13]
```

What the program should do, is reading lines from a file.
the lines have the following Format:

```
"word" \t "word" \t "word" ...
```

The Programm should split each line into a list of strings containing the words

==> list = (word1, word2, word3, ...)

then i wish to test if the word at index 1 matches a given word, and if so i wish to print the word at index 13 (each line has the same ammount of elements)

What i dont understand is, writing:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.split("\t")    
    word = line[1]
    print word
```

works, while

```
for line in file:
    line = line.split("\t")
    word = line[1]
    if my_var in word:
        print line[13]
```

does not work.

Im pretty shure there is an easy solution to this Problem and that i simply cant find it.

Comment: Why are you always doing a lookup on `line[1]`? Why don't you just do `if my_var in line:` ?

Comment: maybey i have a bad understanding of python, but i tried to split a large string(line) into substrings, and then see if this substring matches a given string

Comment: are you sure each line is containing `\t`? maybe there are some lines where words are delimited with whitespace instead of tab?

Comment: yeah, there is a \t, my Problem is: print line[1] works, word = line[1] does not work.

Comment: You should probably post the exact data on which you want to run your code, as well as the exact output you'd expect from your code. "it does not work" is very vague when you don't say what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because of the following line :

```
print line[16]
```

Your splited list hasn't 16 item it is just contain 4 item and you have tried to get the `16`th index.

Comment: the line im using has more than 17 elements, this might have been not obvies in my exaple